# In CoffeeScript, can an instance property declared at the class level refer to another instance property in its definition?

Tags: class, syntax, properties, coffeescript

In CoffeeScript, if I define an instance property in a class constructor, that property can refer to other instance properties in its definition, for example:

```
class Foo
    constructor: (data) ->

        @One = 1

        @Two = @One + 1
```

But what about instance properties declared at the class level? The following does not work:

```
class Foo

    One: 1

    Two: @One + 1
```

In that context, the @ symbol refers to the 'class' itself, not the instance. Likewise simply removing the @ does not work.

Is there a way that one instance property declared at the class level can refer to another instance property in its definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say this:

```
class Foo
    one: 1
```

You're setting `one` on `Foo`'s prototype so you just have to look at `@`'s prototype to get back to where `one` is:

```
class Foo
    one: 1
    two: @::one + 1
```

[Demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20C%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20%40%3A%3Aa%20%2B%201%0Ac%20%3D%20new%20C%0Aconsole.log(c.a%2C%20c.b)%0A)

Note that this even works with subclasses so you do this:

```
class Pancakes extends Foo
    three: @::two + 1
```

and you'll get the expected three.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about the double colon syntax (obviously). Thanks.

Comment: @DanielPratt: Have a look at the bottom of the [Classes, Inheritance and Super](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) section of the docs, there's just one little mention.

Comment: @DanielPratt `::` is just syntax sugar for `.prototype`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an auxiliary variable for that:

```
class Foo
  uno = 1
  One: uno
  Two: uno + 1
```

(the variable can also be called `One`, i just used another name to differentiate it from the property)

Remember, however, that those properties will be in Foo's prototype, not in the Foo "class" itself. This is the generated JS:

```
var Foo;

Foo = (function() {
  var uno;

  function Foo() {}

  uno = 1;

  Foo.prototype.One = uno;

  Foo.prototype.Two = uno + 1;

  return Foo;

})();
```

If you want them to be class properties, you can use @ at the class level:

```
class Foo
  @One = 1
  @Two: @One + 1
```

That way you can access those as `Foo.One` and `Foo.Two`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I gave you an upvote, but I accepted mu's answer as it was a bit closer to what I wanted.

Comment: @DanielPratt Cool. Yeah, mu's answer is better; i hadn't thought about that :). In either case, i assume that you're not actually putting `1` and `2` on those properties, but more interesting things instead, so remember that whatever you put on the prototype will be shared between instances (so beware of mutable things ;).